# __DIR__ not correct with Laravel 5.5 and OVH Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, directory, ovh

I made a website with Laravel 5.5 and Laravel Passport but I have a problem with login in Passport :

> "Key path "file:///home/mylogin/mywebsite/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable"

I found it's nothing related to Passport or Laravel but it's related to `__DIR__` constant.
The `__DIR__` constant in my website folder on OVH return :

> /home/mylogin/mywebsite

Instead of :

> /homez.141/mylogin/mywebsite

How is that possible ? And how should I proceed ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible you have `/home/mylogin/mywebsite` on your localhost? Try running `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: I just tried, same error :/

Comment: Are you using a path helper, like `app_path()` to build the path? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#paths

Comment: In my code I never use and never need to manipulate path, it's like the problem comes with Laravel Passport path. But in the documentation we have only to composer install. On my computer (path : "/Users/username/Documents/Sites/mywebsite") everything works fine but on OVH not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I made a mistake and the path was not in trouble (path changes but it's normal with OVH).

I forgot to run `php artisan passport:install`, so a file was missing (because I work with an dev environment on my computer and I deploy via Github on OVH).